# Data binding with ternary operator to align views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

Can I use data binding with ternary operator to align views.

```
android:layout_toLeftOf= 
"@{value.getUnit().equals(@string/mb)?@+id/lyt_value:@+id/lyt_value2}"
```

Above code gives compilation error 'expr expected'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@{value.getUnit().equals(@string/mb)?@id/lyt_value:@id/lyt_value2}"
```

Comment: Thanks..i'll test..And how can I assign @null to condition?